# Is the entire From Dusk to Dawn in Byakuyakoku quest line unvoiced?

Tags: genshin-impact

Is the entire From Dusk to Dawn in Byakuyakoku quest line unvoiced?

I'm primarily asking so that I may do it silently while on the go, and I would hate missing out on voice-acted lines and would rather take my time at home where I can turn on audio if they voice acted some of the lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's completely unvoiced.